# is it possible move App_Data catalog?

Tags: asp.net

Is there a possibility to move App_Data catalog in ASP .net application? I want it to be stored at C:. I tried to change path in my Web.Config file, but all the time i get a different errors, like access to the path is denied (I have copied all  the permission to my new App_data folder).

Comment: It's generally a good idea to post the exact error messages you get, could you please do it?

Comment: By default IIS won't allow you to access a file outside your site root directory and IIS/ASP.NET users have not rights to access anything outside IIS sites root directory. You you're sure about what you're doing (I mean, you're sure about security implications) then just change those permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to store something in a specific directory like `C:\`, you'll need to make sure that IIS have the appropriate permissions to handle performing these actions (as generally it will only be able to access the directory of the application and IIS' root directory).

If you are debugging your application locally, you might ensure that you are running Visual Studio with Administrative Rights (i.e. `Right-click > Run as Administrator`) as the process spawned from it will likely not be able to access directories that would otherwise require it.

Otherwise, you can check the permissions on one of the following roles, which will vary depending on which version of IIS you are using and ensure that it has the proper permission(s) :

- `IIS_IUSRS`
- `IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool`
- `NETWORK_SERVICE`

Generally speaking, **it's not a good idea to give root access to your applications**. If you are going to be using this in any kind of production manner (outside of a quick and dirty utility application running on your local machine), you should consider using a sub-directory from within your application and referencing the files from there (i.e. drop the files you are attempting to access in your Project and access them relative to your application).